# I know the Servlet configuration is inside web.xml,but where the JSP page server configuration?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

The servlet Configuration is carried out in web.xml, and JSP also need to configure, but where the JSP configuration? Is it automatically configured by Tomcat?

Answer (score -1):

A jsp is accessed directly by its path relative to the context of the web application. For example, in your web application called test

/test/abc/xyz.jsp will access xyz.jsp which should be located in a folder called abc which in turn is a top level folder within your web app.

If you want to configure the jsp in your web.xml, you can use Servlet style declarations. The only difference is that you would use the jsp-file tag rather than servlet-class

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/abc/xyz.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Registering a JSP as a servlet allows you to specify the load order, initialization attributes, and security roles for a JSP, just as you would for a servlet.